# What can be done to increase the number of visits per day?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The last time I checked it, the number of visits per day reported by the [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) was 227. Is there anything we can do to increase it, since the minimum acceptable seems to be more than 500?

Comment: Well providing a comment rather than closevoting the question right away would be great idea!! source:http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3584/a-different-concept-of-difficult-english-words

Comment: Apart that one doesn't exclude the other, I don't see so much questions being closed. Surely, it is not that the problem.

Comment: I think that we should more often invite new EL&U visitors to frequent this site. I have done that several times and I've had positive results.

Comment: Are "number of visits" logins? Questions read by anyone? Something else? I'm just curious what the number means.

Comment: @user3169 I don't think it is just a matter of logging in. It must be the same as for the "consecutive days" shown in the user profile: Just logging in doesn't count as visit, nor does visiting the home page count for that. You have to watch at least the page listing the questions, or a question.

Comment: Then my idea would be that any day you log in and view a question counts as a visit. And only one visit is counted, even if you log in more than once, or read more than one question, in one day. Anyway I think its important to understand the number you are trying to improve.

Comment: @user3169 It is what Area 51 reports for ELL. (See the link I added to the question.)

Comment: I guess one way to increase the number of visits is by increasing number of users/visitors. In order to do that, you need to build site’s reputation. I’m a new user. I’ve been here for a total of 11 days. I never knew about this site. Found out from a link while browsing the English Stack Exchange forum. The second step is to increase the number of questions/answers and posts. There’s no short cut for that.

Comment: How does this (or other SE groups) fare in Google searches? I searched the phrase "english language learning" for results within the last month, and did not find it in the first 50 hits. Of course there are a lot of english language sites out there, and and I'm sure some pay google to get bumped up the list. But I would have hoped to see ELL somewhere in the top listings...  As mentioned by EnglishLearner, I think many who find ELL are already using other SE sites. But some outside influence is needed, I think.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, may I suggest you unaccept the current accepted answer (just for now), to encourage continuing discussion? (I mistakenly asked a duplicate question earlier, and other answers have been merged to this question since. There seemed to be significant interest in continuing the discussion, as traffic hasn't much improved in the last month, and Matt has tagged this question as 'featured' to garner more attention.) At any rate, just a suggestion. I hope this question gets more answers so we can act on them and get more traffic! :)

Comment: I just noticed that this site has been up for only 78 days. What happens after 90 days Beta trial? Are you guys planning to shut it down if it doesn't reach the critical mass?

Comment: @EnglishLearner There are sites that have been in beta phase more than a year.

Comment: @EnglishLearner What kiamlaluno said. See this [stackoverflow blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) for more information about site graduation. :)

Comment: Thanks @WendiKidd and Kiamlaluno. This site should continue to exist beyond the beta. A lot of people haven’t found this site yet, but I’m almost certain that in few years time, ELL will be among the largest site on stack exchange.

Comment: SE should open a sub-website for the questions are deleted. some people like these questions , though.for example, "how to learn English, can i just watch movie a lot?"

Answer (score 11):

There are a couple ways to increase the number of visits:

- Ask really great questions!

  - These show up in the Hot Questions list, attracting attention (and visits) from Stack Excahnge users on other sites. Since these users are already familiar with how the site works (albeit not the specifics of this particular site - yet), they are good to have on the site
  - Well-written, useful, and common questions are more likely to show up in Google (and Bing, Yahoo, etc.) searches, bringing in more traffic and potential new users. The eventual goal is for most of the site's traffic to come from search engines
- Share Questions and Answers!

  - Click the "share" link under a particularly great post, and share the link with people you know (email lists, Facebook, Twitter, other Stack Exchange sites, etc.). Make sure it's relevant to the topic at hand, so it doesn't get ignored or viewed as spam.
- Visit the site every day

  - Read posts and vote.
  - Ask any questions you come up with, and answer any questions you can (feeds back into the first bullet)

Answer (score 7):

I think part of the problem stems from our sister site ELU (https://english.stackexchange.com/).

I barely, if ever, see a question from ELU redirected to ELL. Their FAQ also makes no reference of ELL either. There's even a header in ELU's FAQ that's literally called "[Where can I find answers to simple and basic questions?](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#where-can-i-find-answers-to-simple-and-basic-questions)" where ELL would be a perfect fit.

I think this whole situation is somewhat odd, ELU is not for questions from people beginning to learn the English language, in fact questions by those people is somewhat frowned upon. However, I do not see much effort put into it to redirect those questions to the proper site.

Comment: I’ve been lurking around quite a bit on the ELU forum. I didn’t even know that ELL existed until a month ago. I came here via a link from a user post on ELU. If I didn’t encounter that post on that day a month ago, then I’d probably not even know about this forum. It’s very hard to find ELL. Oh, BTW, can you please correct the link in your post.

Comment: @Carlo_R. +1 for suggesting that ELU should be for Advanced English Language/Learners.

Comment: @EnglishLearner A typo and the wrong site altogether, wow that was a really bad link. Thanks for catching that one :)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with **shadowmanwkp**, In my opinion more question are closed on ELU everyday because of being **too  basic**, than total questions posted on ELL. So we should ask the people, who close vote the questions on ELU, that they should migrate it to ELL instead(That is if the question satisfies the criterion of ELL).

This will help filter up the content of ELU and crank up the traffic of ELL.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to migrate basic questions from ELU to here.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally visit more often if I could take some of the rep from EL&U with me. Very frustrating not being able to edit a question without peer review on such a slow site.

I also support the "Migrate to ELL from ELU"